# Error: Could not find or load main class ReadFile recieved when attempting to run code

Tags: java

When I run some code I have compiled (with no errors) I receive the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ReadFile
```

The code I am trying to run is the file *ReadFile.java*:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file_name = "hello.txt";
        try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();
            int i;
            for (i=0; i<aryLines.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage() );
        }
    }
    private String path;
    public ReadFile(String file_path) {
        path = file_path;
    }
    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        int numberOfLines = readLines();
        String[] textData = new String[numberOfLines];
        int i;
        for (i=0;i<numberOfLines;i++) {
            textData[i] = textReader.readLine();
        }
        textReader.close();
        return textData;
    }   
    int readLines() throws IOException {
        FileReader file_to_read = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(file_to_read);
        String aLine;
        int numberOfLines = 0;
        while (( aLine = bf.readLine()) != null) {
            numberOfLines++;
        }
        bf.close();
        return numberOfLines;
    }
}
```

and *hello.txt* is as follows:

```
Hello World
Hello Solar System
Hello Galaxy
```

I am a beginner and am not sure why I am returned with this error, can anyone help?

Comment: How did you run it?  Does the class belong in a package?  Is it jar'ed?

Comment: I ran it using the command *java ReadFile* in command prompt and it is a single class file, not belonging to anything.

Comment: And you've compiled the source file first?

Comment: Yep, I compiled it using the command *javac ReadFile.java* first and it compiled with no errors

Comment: So, the one of other possible issues is `ReadFile` has a `package` declaration as the first line in the source file (not shown in your example).  If your list the contents of the directory where `ReadFile.java` resides, does it contain a `ReadFile.class` file?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post an image. I have done exactly the same command as you in command prompt and I still receive the error. The code above is an exact copy of the code in the file and there is absolutely nothing else present. The code editor I am using is notepad++.

Comment: Command prompt: http://i.imgur.com/IoV8z9r.png Code: http://i.imgur.com/9LDiFPY.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, change directories to the location of your source file..

[image: Cmd01]

Use the Java Compiler to compile the source file to a `.class` file

```
javac ReadFile.java
```

[image: Cmd02]

Now use Java to run the resulting `.class` file...

```
java ReadFile
```

[image: Cmd03]

(Note, I didn't have a file to read, but that wasn't my goal)

**** WARNING ****

This will only work if the `ReadFile.java` file does not start with a `package` declaration.  If it does, it will change the way that the class has to be run!!

Comment: This is what I have been doing but I am getting the error shown above. I don't see the difference in what I am doing compared to what you are doing. I will edit the question with images of my file directory

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post an image. I have done exactly the same command as you in command prompt and I still receive the error. The code above is an exact copy of the code in the file and there is absolutely nothing else present. The code editor I am using is notepad++.

Comment: Yep, that's how I created the `.java` file (Notepad++). Try deleting the `.class` file and trying again...

Comment: Command prompt: i.imgur.com/IoV8z9r.png Code: i.imgur.com/9LDiFPY.png

Comment: Do you have more then one version of Java installed?

Comment: I have one version of JDK installed: Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 5 (64-bit)

Comment: Although I have noticed I do also have the following: "Java 7 Update 55" and "Java 8 Update 5 (64-bit)".

Comment: Okay, it "could" be that you're compiling with one version of Java and running with another, although I would have expected a class version error instead. Try using an absolute path to to each, for example `"\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javac.exe"`

Comment: Why is this being such a nightmare. Command is now not happy with me even using program files. I am typing "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javac.exe ReadFile.java" and am returned with the error "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Also if I try using an underscore within the space: "C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javac.exe ReadFile.java" I get the error "The system cannot find the path specified.". What is wrong now? The path is definitely specified and there.

Comment: No space at all doesn't work either.

Comment: You have to quote the command, for example it should read `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\javac.exe" ReadFile.java` - This is (one of the reasons) why I use an IDE

Comment: Just did that, same error message again `Error: Could not find or load main class ReadFile`. I will probably have to if this happens again and again, I'm just happy with a very simple layout of notepad++. Do you have any other ideas of what this could be?

Comment: I'm going to completely uninstall and reinstall java

Comment: I doubt it will help, but you could try `java -cp . ReadFile`

Comment: Ok re-installing didn't help but doing that did! From that do you know what was wrong?

Comment: If I knew what was wrong it'd be fixed by now.  What is the value of the classpath environment variable (`echo %classpath%`)